# Can you listen to your computer's sound with a soundcard

Tags: sound, production

I would like to buy a Lexicon Alpha Studio, but I wanted to make sure that I can listen to my computers sound through it (it seems logical to me). Because my computer's jack plug is broken and my current adapter reduces low frequencies so that's not good for music production.

But in every review or video I see about this sound card (or any other sound card), people just use it to record sound, not to play sound, so that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: what kind of computer do you have?  Mac/PC/Linux?  If you set Lexicon Alpha Studio as your main output, then you'll notice that all your audio will be sent out to the device's monitor outputs.  Therefore, bypassing your headphone jack on your computer.

Comment: It's a Windows so I see how to do this. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can select the Lexicon as your computer's default audio output for all purposes.  There are line level and headphone output sockets.  Not, I think, the stereo 3.5mm jacks that your computer probably had, but a cheap adapter cable will sort that out.

If you intend to do music production, you probably want to go a bit up-market from this device.  But it should do a fine job at replacing a broken output jack on your computer.

Comment: *"If you intend to do music production, you probably want to go a bit up-market from this device."* I'd add the word *large-scale* to that sentence. So many people out there "producing" music with laptops and budget gear.

Answer (score 2):

Soundcards are classified by (amongst other things) their number of inputs and outputs. In general, a soundcard that has outputs is one that you'll be able to listen to (from the outputs!). This Lexicon is 2 in*, 2 out, so we expect to be able to listen to 2 channels (which should be fine for normal stereo listening.)

Another question is *what* outputs it has; if you want to plug in headphones, it's not much good if your soundcard only has XLR outputs. This Lexicon seems to have 1/4 inch, RCA, and headphone outputs - if one of those fits your needs, you should be fine.

<sub>* actually they seem to describe it as '2x2' in, i.e. 2 stereo channels</sub>

Comment: Indeed I wanted jack and not xlr outputs, so the Lexicon Alpha seem to have this, and if I remember right it also has an xlr mic input, so that would allow me to use good hq xlr mics

Answer (score 1):

I should note that the Lexicon Alpha solution is actually quite solid yet very limited in regards to how many channels you have to work with. That being said, as I own one, it is fantastic for on-the-go gigs such as recital recordings and so on. But, as Lawrence Payne previously noted, you should certainly go up-market if you intend to do some more serious production. It's great for getting your feet wet, though.

At any rate, the Lexicon Alpha is indeed an Input/Output interface. The back side allows to plug in microphones and such, and it has audio output RCA jacks on the back side, but on the front side, on the right side of all the controls and knobs, is a standard 3.5mm headphone jack.

You may either plug a 3.5mm audio cable to your speakers or to a headphone set to that jack, or you may plug speakers to the back RCA jacks. The monitor mix knob to the left of the front headphone jack allows you to shift the sound to the monitor headphone jack (by turning it to the right) or to the RCA jacks on the back (by turning it to the left).

Comment: Thanks, I read a lot of reviews saying that Lexicon Alpha was a very good low-cost soundcard, that's why I was interested in it. And I think I still need to get my feet on mixing and mastering before buying a more expansive and serious sound card